# Links won't open in Fedora 12 using Firefox

Tags: firefox, fedora

While I am a Linux user I tend to be largely a GUI computer user in Linux. I use Fedora 12 and Firefox Web Browser. Firefox 2098.

Firefox works fine excepting one problem which I'll describe now.

When I attempt to open a Link which a friend or Company has sent to me, the Link will not open. I get the following message on a small screen when I attempt to open a Link:

> Failed to execute child process "/usr/lib/firefox-3.5.4/firefox" (No such file or directory)

If I right click the Link I am offered the option of  "Copy Link Location". I copy the Link Location then I go to my web browser – which is Firefox – I Click on "File/Open Location" and paste the Link Location and link opens just fine.

Is there a workaround for this problem?

Comment: Hi William. I have removed your email address from your post. You seem to have posted an email-formatted message here and so everything's all over the place. I have done a general tidy up but in future it's best to type in your message from scratch rather than cutting and pasting in a structued format from another app. You have also referred to 'Firefox 2098', which does not exist and this may be why you are having problems with your question - have a check of your system and make the necessary edits to your text above.

Comment: @William - what Window Manager are you using? Gnome?

Answer (score 0):

The key to answering this question is likely "***What application is the link you're opening located within?***"

**Application Level Fix**

That application most likely has a setting somewhere for how to handle URLs. It sounds like your settings are calling on firefox, expecting it to be available from a location where it's not.

**Window Manager Level Fix**

If the application doesn't offer an obvious means of managing URL clicking functionality, then settings from your Window Manager may be getting inherited/used. Check your Window Manager's configuration for default web browser settings.

**Command Line Fix**

Failing the above two, I think you can probably just do the following to resolve your issue at the command line:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/firefox-3.5.4; sudo ln -s `which firefox` /usr/lib/firefox-3.5.4/firefox
```

Comment: I'm out of my league. I sent threee versions ofmy letter before the Moderator told me how have the question accepted. ON the final version I sisn't include Firefox 2098---but it appeared in the accepted version anyway. I do use Gnome. I don't know how to check my Window Manager's configuration for default web browser settings.

Comment: @William: What window manager are you using? Gnome? KDE? XFCE?

Comment: William here again. I use Gnome as Window Manager. In desparation I ran the command White Phoenix gave me, just above, and it was accepted. I haven't received a "Link" to test the command as yet.

Comment: 7-13-2011  The Commandline command White Phoenix gave me yesterday solved my problem perfectly. Here's my thanks and Salute.

Comment: @William H. Ferguson: Glad you're back on track. Please consider marking my answer as "accepted"... Up-votes are always nice too :)